# How to store AWS secret in yubikey?

Tags: amazon-web-services, cryptography, yubikey, aws-access-policy

Im trying to store AWS access secret key in yubikey,but, as static password in "scan mode", it is not possible to store, because AWS secret exceeds 38 characters.

Now im thinking of way to store AWS secret, as in "official" way they do with SSH --> https://gist.github.com/artizirk/d09ce3570021b0f65469cb450bee5e29 , but no luck for now ( and i have very few expectation for this "path" )

Maybe someone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is impossible, we moved on to the AWS SSO